# The source of report definition has not been specified

Tags: reporting-services

I get following error

```
the source of report definition has not been specified
```

Here is the code I am using

```
ReportViewer ReportViewer1 =null;

ReportPath = "Reports/BatchOtherComments.rdlc";
...
        rptData.DataSetName = "spReport_LoanSummaryBatchOther";
        objReportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("spReport_LoanSummaryBatchOther", rptData.Tables[0]);
        rep.DataSources.Add(objReportDataSource);

        Warning[] warnings;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        string deviceInfo;
        string[] streamids;
        deviceInfo =
          "<DeviceInfo>" +
          "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
          "  <PageSize>A4</PageSize>" +
          "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
          "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
          "  <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>" +
          "  <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>" +
          "  <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>" +
          "  <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>" +
          "</DeviceInfo>";
        byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:/Users/wnaeem/Sample.PDF", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ;
}
finally
{
    ReportViewer1.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note that you can edit your question to make it more readable, and thus enjoyable, and thus more likely to draw answers.

Comment: Apart from that, I don't see your problem? You don't set a ReportPath in your code, so you get an error that the report hasn't been set. That's what you'd expect, right?